# When is this needed in JavaScript / Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to JavaScript. I've read that the context of *this* changes depending on how the function is being invoked (ie: from a variable, as a callback etc). I cannot find anything that says when I need to use *this* and when I don't. I've seen lots of code use *this* and seen code without it.

ie: Here is a for loop inside a function. It works. It doesn't use *this*

```
var output="";

for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    output = input.charAt(i) + output;
}
return output;
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate, and this post has a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pretty complicated concept in Javascript. There aren't strict rules about when you *have* to use `this`, but there are some situations where it's useful.

[Mozilla Developer Network - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called

[Understand JavaScript’s “this” With Clarity, and Master It](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

One example where you almost always use `this` is when using an ES5 constructor. You apply properties to the constructor using `this` and then they are created as object properties on the instance created.

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
}

var me = new Person('yourname');
me.name // 'yourname'
```